# ImportError: No module named scapy.all for WifiJammer.py

Tags: python, wifi, scapy

I found this this GitHub page https://github.com/bhikandeshmukh/Wi-Fi-Jammer
and I proceeded to run the first two installation commands. However when I run `python wifijammer.py` I get ImportError: No module named scapy.all.

I installed scapy already. any ideas on how to solve the issue?

Thanks in advance.